# Getting an error (CS0012) telling me to add a reference to DevEx.Component.v9.1 but I already have a reference to the same component, but v16.1

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm converting a project from .NET 2.0 to 4.0 and DevExpress v9.1 to v16.1. Everything was going smoothly until I got an error saying that the type 'XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' is defined in the older assembly.

I've already deleted and re-added the correct reference. There isn't anything weird going on in the .csproj file either; the reference there is correct.

The error happens here

```cs
ErrorHandler.Instance.SetError(regInfoGridView, row, "str", i, "str")
```

This is the header for SetError (from metadata):

```cs
public void SetError(GridView grid, DataRow row, string columnName, int rowHandle, string errMessage);
```

The code seems simple enough, so I'm not sure why it might be asking for an old version of 'GridView'.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to use the [DevExpress Project Converter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/ProjectConverter/2529/Project-Converter) tool installed with DevExpress .NET components to update your projects when upgrading to a new version.

The Project Converter replaces references to outdated DevExpress assemblies in your projects with references to the most recent libraries.

The following files are updated during the conversion process:

- project files (.csproj and .vbproj);
- resource files (.resx) for forms that were localized in the Visual Studio Form Designer;
- web application files (Web.config, .aspx, .ascx, .asax and .master);
- other files, including .cs, .vb, .xaml, .skin, .config, .config.xml, .licx, .svc, .refresh, .uitest, and .lsml.

[Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/08vtxpe6jLA)